# How to check if a table has contents in it

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

How do I check if a table has contents? Honestly I still don't have any initial codes for it. Do I code it in VB or just use a query?

Answer (score 2):

you definitely need to ask SQL server, so why not just querying 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE" ?
which you can put it in a stored procedure.

even you can parametrise the procedure with table name and run exec sql command.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `SELECT COUNT(*)` unless you actually care about the actual count - this can be an expensive operation on large tables. If all you care about is whether there are rows or not, much better to use:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) NULL FROM dbo.MyTable)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'There are rows.';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'There are no rows.';
END
```

If you don't need to be up-to-the-second, you can use the DMVs for this kind of check. Specifically:

```
SELECT SUM(row_count)
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable');
```

The DMV is not always precise due to in-flight transactions and deferred updates, but is generally reliable for ballpark estimates.

Comment: hi .. thank you so much .. this is not the actual code that i needed but this gave me an idea ... thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

Install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  You can then view the contents and structure of your tables, easily, through the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=myDb;Integrated Security=True")
Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM myTable", con)
con.Open()
Dim count As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
con.Close()
```